# How to read Barcode reader from the camera instance in windows 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-8.1

How can I read bar-code And QR code from my camera using XAML C# in windows 8 application?
I had tried using the **CaptureElement** with the reference from this http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/walkthrough-capturing-photos-in-your.html and implement some decode logic like this

The problem with this is that,I am not able to get how to scan the particular object of the bar-code so that it decode it and give me the proper result.

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="900" Width="900">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Preview"></TextBlock>
            <CaptureElement x:Name="Cap1" Height="700" Width="250"></CaptureElement>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="but1" Click="but1_Click_1" Content="Take" Height="150" Width="250"></Button>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Snapshot"></TextBlock>
            <Image x:Name="Img1" Height="600" Width="600"></Image>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ScanResult" FontSize="20" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

**C#**

```
private async void Page_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cameras = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
        if (cameras.Count < 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings;
        if (cameras.Count == 1)
        {
            settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameras[0].Id }; // 0 => front, 1 => back
        }
        else
        {
            settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameras[1].Id }; // 0 => front, 1 => back
        }

        await _MediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

        Cap1.Source = _MediaCapture;

        await _MediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
    }



private async void but1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScanResult.Text = "";
        var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var Opt = CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting;
        var file1 = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(name, Opt);
        var imgformat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreatePng();
        await _MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgformat, file1);
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file1.Path));
    Img1.Source = bitmapImage;
        var stream = await file1.OpenReadAsync();

        // initialize with 1,1 to get the current size of the image
        var writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
        writeableBmp.SetSource(stream);
        // and create it again because otherwise the WB isn't fully initialized and decoding
        // results in a IndexOutOfRange
        writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(writeableBmp.PixelWidth, writeableBmp.PixelHeight);
        stream.Seek(0);
        writeableBmp.SetSource(stream);

        var result = ScanBitmap(writeableBmp);
        if (result != null)
        {
            ScanResult.Text += result.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ScanResult.Text = "no result";
        }

    }

    private object ScanBitmap(WriteableBitmap writeableBmp)
    {
        try
        {
            var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader
                {
                    TryHarder = true,
                    AutoRotate = true
                };

            var result = barcodeReader.Decode(writeableBmp);

            if (result != null)
            {
                Img1.Source = writeableBmp;
            }
            return result;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Phone just use [Zxing.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile), as such

### BarcodeScanner.Xaml.cs

```
buttonScan.Click += (sender, e) => {

    var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner(this.Dispatcher);
    var result = await scanner.Scan();

  if (result != null)
    Debug.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + result.Text);
};
```

If you planning to WinRT app, you should do something like [this](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net/blob/master/Clients/WindowsRTDemo).

Snap picture and try to recognize untill find a barcode. There is no better way to do it. Actually you can improve that code such

```
var llPhoto = await mediaCapture.PrepareLowLagPhotoCaptureAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg());
var photo = await llPhoto.CaptureAsync();

WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)photo.Frame.Width, (int)photo.Frame.Height);
wbmp.SetSource(photo.Frame.AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream());

result = ScanBitmap(wbmp);
```

Note: If you will try the 2nd solution in Windows phone, it will be too slow such snapping & processing each image in 2-3 second.